# get selected image from gallery into imageview

Tags: android, xml

I am facing a problem in selecting the image from a gallery and setting it into the `imageview`. Suppose I have two activities; `mainActivity` containing buttons for gallery and `secondactivity` containing the `imageview` in which the image has to be displayed.

```
 b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(
    Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
   }
   });
```

Please give me the individual code for both....

Comment: SO isn't for finding people to write code for you. Tell us what errors  or unexpected results you're getting, and post more code so we can help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

here is the code to load an image from gallery:

```
public class ImageGalleryDemoActivity extends Activity {


    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: really, I appreciate your answer but i want to open or pass the image in new activity.....

Comment: @amanjain4all then farward these two selectedImage and filePathColumn in intent's put extra and receive that in next activity to load the selected image.

Answer (score 9):

**with `Picasso` it can be done in single line and You dont need to make `cursor query`**

I have extended it for better understanding :-

Pick Image

```
    public void pickImage() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);

    }
```

Load Image

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
    
                    Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
    
                    Picasso.with(MainActivity1.this).load(selectedImageURI).noPlaceholder().centerCrop().fit()
                            .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1));
                }
    
            }
        }
```

Comment: SELECT_PICTURE ?? what is this ?

Comment: A random integer constant which is used to ID onActivityResult() callback.  The constant value of SELECT_PICTURE passed during startActivityForResult method should match with resultCode of onActivityResult.

Comment: Is there a similar way for glide?

Answer (score 4):

In my case work this solution

```
 private void OpenGallery(){
    Intent getImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    getImageIntent .setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(getImageIntent , IMAGE_PICKER );
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode== IMAGE_PICKER  && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri fullPhotoUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(fullPhotoUri);
    }
}
```

You can share URI using putExtra("fullPhotoUri", fullPhotoUri.toString()) between activities.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }
    }
```

Here some examples

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/20/select-an-image-from-gallery-in-android-and-show-it-in-an-imageview/

Comment: i want to open gallery images into different activity???? so plz give code individually.........

Answer (score 1):

**To Pick Image from gallery, use this code.**

```
btn_imageSetter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), IMAGE_PICKER);

    }
});
```

Now use this Method to Set the image to the ImageViewer

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        try{
            final Uri uriImage = data.getData();
            final InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uriImage);
            final Bitmap imageMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            iv_image.setImageBitmap(imageMap);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Image was not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


}
```