# Imageviewer update not changing the icon

Tags: android, imageview

So here my code in MainActivity, when clicking the appliance_icon which is a ImageView it will lead me to my gallery which i can choose pictures.

```
 final Dialog addingDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
 addingDialog.setTitle("Adding New Appliance");
 addingDialog.setContentView(R.layout.adding_appliance);

 final Button done = (Button)addingDialog.findViewById(R.id.done);
 final Button appliance_color = (Button)addingDialog.findViewById(R.id.appliance_color);
 final ImageView appliance_icon = (ImageView)addingDialog.findViewById(R.id.appliance_icon);



 appliance_icon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Intent i = new Intent(
                                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                                appliance_icon.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));          

                            }                               
                        });
```

My problem is that whenever i choose a new picture it does not update my imageview and also the imageview will only update at the second time i press it.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();


        }
    }
```

Comment: declare `appliance_icon` at **class level** and in *onActivityResult(...)* set bitmap on that `ImageView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare image view before class start,

```
ImageView appliance_icon;
```

use this in imageview on click(),

```
 appliance_icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.xxxx);
     appliance_icon .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent,100);
        }
        });
```

use this in onActivityResult,

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {     
                Bitmap bmImg=null;
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    final Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    final Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                    intent.setDataAndType(selectedImage, "image/*");
                    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    if (cursor != null) {
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

                        bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(columnIndex));

                        cursor.close();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                    appliance_icon .setImageBitmap(bmImg);


                }

            }.execute();


        }
}
```

Comment: where do u initialize variable g here?

Comment: image is imageview variable. ImageView image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.xxxx);

Comment: imageview is not on mainactivity, it is called thru a dialog, see edited codes above

Comment: ImageView appliance_icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.appliance_icon); appliance_icon.setImageBitmap(bmImg); Use this code in onPostExecute

Comment: i got a solution. Declare user ImageView appliance_icon before class starting point and get use the edited code.

Comment: wow bro your awesome, thanks for helping me. the solution was so simple yet very confusing

Answer (score 1):

Could you just set the image in the onActivityResult method ?

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        updatePicture();

    }
}


public void updatePicture() {

      appliance_icon.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath)); 

}
```

Comment: theres an error because appliance_icon is came from a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look into this question, it might fulfill your need.
[get selected image from gallery into imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197487/get-selected-image-from-gallery-into-imageview)

Comment: thats where my code from but my problem is because my imageview is from a dialog so its layout is not from the MainActivity so i cannot use the code. see after cursor.close() i replace it and put it after my startActivityforResult